# How to manage AWS glue jobs from a microservice need suggestions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

We have a requirement to manage the AWS glue job from a microservice (rest service ). the microservice will provide a REST endpoint to start, stop and find the status of a glue job. We are looking for suggestion on how this can be achieved. What we know is using AWS-SDK we can achieve it. it would be very helpful if anyone can share their experience.

Comment: How are you planning to deploy the microservice?

Comment: Its on AWS as a docker containerized application.

Comment: AWS already exposes REST endpoints for all of it's API's. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_Operations.html

Comment: If you already know how to use AWS sdk, what are you looking for in specific?

Comment: I am looking for something like a proven architecture to do this kind of work. Or any experience in developing this sort of application